# Solution for Browser back button tracking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

I want to track browser back button.
If the user click on the browser back button, It should ask user to logout in pop-up confirm box. If the user press "ok", user account should log out. If user press "cancel", user should stay on the same page.
I already visited:

- [Confirm browser back button else stay on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681093/confirm-browser-back-button-else-stay-on-page)
- [How can I override the OnBeforeUnload dialog and replace it with my own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own)
- [Client/JS Framework for "Unsaved Data" Protection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140460/client-js-framework-for-unsaved-data-protection)
- [Alert user when they hit the browser back button - with good reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033874/alert-user-when-they-hit-the-browser-back-button-with-good-reson)

But I am not getting any positive solution for my problem.
I already tried this code

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) {            
    if(confirm('logout ?'))
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Dont use browser navigations');
        return false;
    }
}
```

`If` part is perfectly working. But `else` part, after alert box the browser shows the default dialog box.
If I use `return true` instead of `return` in the `if` part, the browser pops up the confirm box and shows default dialog box followed that. If I use `return`, It is just showing the confirm box and proceeds the action.

So, in the same way I'm using return false in `else` part. If I use `return false` in `else` part alert box is display after confirm cancel action. Then browser's default dialog box is asking to leave the page or stay on this page.

I want to use another solution instead of `return false` to make the condition false. If user click the cancel button in confirm box it should do nothing. It should stay on the same page.
See the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/psF6m/) demo

Comment: You have to test this in many browsers. E.g. Firefox doesn't show the message created by your `return`. MSIE 10 cannot handle return false, it shows 'false'. Read the docs for `onbeforeunload`, I'm afraid you are not using it how it was meant.

Comment: I'm working in Firefox only... Did you see my js fiddle demo?http://jsfiddle.net/psF6m/

Comment: Your code will also annoy users who want to close the window/tab, not just those hitting 'back'

Comment: I am handling web application. So user should use my application wizard controls for navigation. If User use browser navigation like back button, application session should close or logout. So, I want to get confirmation from the user to logout.  So only I am trying to do this.

Comment: If you could accepting not to show a confirm button, but just be a little safer that users are logged off, then you could have a look at a solution in one of my projects: [github gist](https://gist.github.com/hgoebl/7446989)

Comment: I edited my previous comment.

Comment: @hgoebl, Thanks for taking effort. But, Sorry I could not understand your code... could you please show any little fiddle demo for this?

Comment: http://html5doctor.com/history-api/

Comment: There is any option to write 'window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) { if(return true){ aleret(true message);}else{alert(false message)}}